# Linking a dynamic library compiled from Rust with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, rust

I'd like to build a dynamic library from a Rust program and link it to an existing C++ project. 
For the C++ project, we are stuck on using gcc for compilation (a relatively old gcc 4.8.2, but I'm also trying with gcc 7.3.0 with the same issue).

This is a minimal example of the issue:

src/lib.rs

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn hello() {
  println!("Hello World, Rust here!");
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "gcc-linking"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ..
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[dependencies]
```

hello.cpp:

```
extern "C" void hello();

int main() {

    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I link with `clang`, everything is fine:

```
cargo build --lib
clang -L target/debug -l gcc_linking hello.cpp -o hello
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=target/debug:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./hello
```

As expected, this results in:

```
Hello World, Rust here!
```

But if I try to link this with `gcc`, I get the following linking error:

```
gcc -L target/debug -l gcc_linking hello.cpp -o hello
```

Output:

```
/tmp/ccRdGJOK.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Looking at the dynamical library:

```
# objdump -T output
0000000000043f60 g    DF .text  0000000000000043  Base        hello
# nm -gC output
0000000000043f60 T hello
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with mangling of function names, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried "cdylib" as the `crate-type` instead of "dylib"?

Comment: Same problem with "cdylib"

Comment: it works for me with gcc 8.2.0 on a mac

Comment: Try putting the `-l gcc_linking` _after_ the `hello.cpp` on the gcc command-line.

Comment: OMG, putting `-l gcc_linking` after `hello.cpp` *did* indeed work. Thank you very much @Jmb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jmb suggested, the solution was to change the order of arguments to `gcc` and list the shared library *after* the C++ file:

```
gcc -L target/debug hello.cpp -l gcc_linking -o hello
```

Comment: Next time, use CMake instead ;)